# ether faucet error whenever i am trying to get ethers for rinkeby testnet from https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, rinkeby

when ever i am trying to get ethers (rinkeby) from https://faucet.rinkeby.io/  it is giving me this error.

Faucet offline: context deadline exceeded

even without entry my url it is giving the error.

help pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rinkeby network currently have problem about the consensus protocol and it was stuck at a block number, please go to below links for more details information

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17596

https://blog.infura.io/rinkeby-consensus-post-mortem-4abbcace0539